# Pass Props To Functions In The Render Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have some values coming back from my Redux store that I'd like to run through a function for some formatting and processing.

In the example below it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone provide me a solution where I can run functions from the render method, pass prop data to those functions as well as return values from those functions right inline with the surrounding JSX?

I want to be able to run the same function and pass in different props wherever I want in the render method.

These are the errors I get in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$7wovvyrz8nu' of null

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'myValue' of null
```

And my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    propsData: store.myData.propsData
  };
})

class MyApp extends Component {

reverseFunc(value){

const reverseValue = value.reverse();

return {
  reverseValue
  }
}

render() {
  return <h1> My props data reversed is: {this.reverseFunc(this.props.propsData.myValue)} </h1>;
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Redux store example:

```
const initialState = {
  propsData: null
}

switch (action.type) {
case LOAD_PROPS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    propsData: action.data
   }
 }
}
return state
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'it doesn't seem to work'?  Console errors would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print an `Object`s or `Array`s in JSX, so your only option will be to convert them into strings, which is why I added toString in my example. If you're reversing a string, uncomment line 3 of the func and delete the first line of the `reverseFunc`.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

@connect(store => {
  return {
    propsData: store.myData.propsData
  };
})
class MyApp extends Component {
  reverseFunc(value){
    if(value !== null){
      return value.reverse().toString();
    }
    // OR
    // return value.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        My props data reversed is: {this.reverseFunc(this.props.propsData)}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: I get this error with your solution: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'reverse' of null`

Comment: @fromspace This would mean store.myData.propsData is null? Is this correct? try the updated code.

Comment: It is, why is that? I know one fix is to declare default props, is that right?

Comment: @fromspace You can use an initial state in your store since you're using Redux :) Post your store if you need help on this.

Comment: in my store the state of the prop I'm trying to access is set to null. I tried setting it to a string and an number but I still get the same error.

Comment: updated store example, also showed exactly what I'm trying to access in my props value

Comment: @fromspace can you post your entire store file you’re missing the function in your snippet